# Check if $f_y(x) = \frac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1}$ converges uniformly when $y \to + \infty$ and $x \in [1, + \infty)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Check if $\;f_y(x) = \dfrac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1}\;$ converges uniformly when $y \to + \infty$ and $x \in [1, + \infty)$.

My work:

Firstly, we must find $\;\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1}\;$ and that limit is equal to $\,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\,$.

Then we are looking for $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \sup_{x \geq 1} \left| \frac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1} - \frac{\pi}{2} \right|$$ If that limit is equal to $0$ then $f_y$ converges uniformly.

Let $\;\varphi(x) =  \dfrac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1} - \dfrac{\pi}{2}\,$. Easily we can see that $\varphi' > 0$  so that means that $\sup_{x\geq 1} \varphi$ is achieved when $x\to \infty$, which is equal to $$ \sup_{x \geq 1} \left|\frac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right|= \left| \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} y}{y+1} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right|$$ From that we get that $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \sup_{x \geq 1} \left| \frac{y \arctan(xy)}{y+1} - \frac{\pi}{2} \right|= 0$$ so it converges uniformly. But, result in my book is that it does not converges uniformly. Where I am wrong?

Comment: The supremum of  $|\varphi(x)|$ is attained at  $x=1.$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge 1$ we have
$$0\le {\pi\over 2}- f_y(x)={\pi \over 2}-{y\arctan xy\over y+1}\le {\pi\over 2}-{y\arctan y\over y+1}$$
Hence the limit is uniform.

If we extend the interval to $x>0$ then the uniform convergence fails as
$${\pi\over 2}-f_y(y^{-1})={\pi\over 2}-{\pi\over 4}{y\over y+1}>{\pi \over 4}$$